# How to query schema and all time series in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

How do I query the schema of Apache IoTDB? Does Java currently have such an API open? Also, does Java have an API to check all the time series stored in IoTDB. Also, I want to check the schema and all time series both in the console of IoTDB and in code. Any ways that I can get these results in both situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the schema of Apache IoTDB, then `show timeseries root.xxx` can do that. If you want to check all time series in Apache IoTDB, you can use `show timeseries`. Currently, the two query statements can be used to check your results in console, and for coding situations, you can use`session.executeQueryStatement` and then parse the results.